# Bootstrap - select and button next to each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `<select>` and a button next to each other and wanted to style them with bootstrap. 
`Select` without class looks like this:

[image]

`select` with `class="form-control"` looks like this:
[image]

Notice, that the button is now *under* select. I'm not sure, which CSS property is responsible for this. What should I change, to have button next to the select?

Comment: There is a better answer of the accepted one (the mine), can you please consider for the other users, that it would be a better solution and accept it instead of mine ? Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following Boostrap syntax :

*You should add `form-inline` class to your form, see the [official doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)*

### Official example

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem with `form-inline` is that it's a form style, i.e. your form is either inline or it is not. Meaning, you can't fix inline with none inline elements. They are trying to address this in Bootstrap 4 though: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21581

Answer (score 43):

You can wrap the `<select>` and the `<button>` in an `input-group`:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>Select option..</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>            
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" tabindex="-1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

This way you can use a normal form and just group one select and button together.

Check out the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jz1L4qj8/)

Comment: The best choice if you have another inputs in addition to a select in your form.

Comment: Just as a heads up, the official Bootstrap notes that one should avoid using `<select>` elements in an `input-group` as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers (e.g. Safari and Chrome). This can be easily seen by looking at the jsfiddle that is linked here in Chrome. The button does not quite fit next to the select as it still has curved edges. I do not currently know of a solution to this issue.

Comment: @Wingpad, Just thought it useful to others to mention that, as of today, this input-group appears good in chrome.

Comment: This is the best solution. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach is to wrap the controls in a `flex` div:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <select class="form-control">...</select>
  <!-- optional spacer: <div style="width: 8px;" /> -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. perfectly suited my requirement.

Answer (score 5):

### Bootstrap 4

Use helper classes! `d-flex` will do just fine.

```css
body {

  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

      <!-- Wrap your 2 elements in a d-flex -->

      <div class="d-flex">
        <select class="form-control mr-2">
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Select" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is what you want...

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
    <div style={{width: "80%"}}>
        <Textbox
          attributesInput={{ // Optional.
            id: 'listPrice',
            name: 'listPrice',
            type: 'text', 
            placeholder: 'Please Enter List Price',
          }}
          class="field inputField"
          value={listPrice} // Optional.[String].Default: "".
          onChange={(value) => handleSetListPrice(value)} // Required.[Func].Default: () => {}. Will return the value.
          onBlur={() => {}} // Optional.[Func].Default: none. In order to validate the value on blur, you MUST provide a function, even if it is an empty function. Missing this, the validation on blur will not work.
          validationOption={{
            type: 'number', // Optional.[String].Default: "string". Validation type, options are ['string', 'number', 'alphanumeric', 'alpha'].
            min: 1, // Optional.[Number].Default: 0. Validation of min length when validationOption['type'] is string, min amount when validationOption['type'] is number.
            max: 100, // Optional.[Number].Default: 0. Validation of max length when validationOption['type'] is string, max amount when validationOption['type'] is number.
            mantissa: 2 // Optional.[Number].Default: -1. Number precision.
          }}
        /> 
    </div>
    <div style={{width: "20%"}}>
        <Select  options={[ { value: 'eth', label: 'ETH' }, { value: 'xyzx', label: 'XYZ' } ]} />
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As Luke stated, but use input-group-append for the button span. That get rid of the roundness on the button and makes for a better matchup.