# Bootstrap - select and button next to each other in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I could find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573822/bootstrap-select-and-button-next-to-each-other) here but it is out of date because the answers are wrong. They are not valid in bootlint.com.

[Here](http://bootsnipp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/iframe/g07Xd) is a bootsnipp example. but that example is not valid in bootlint.

It returns the E006 error.

How can I validate it?

EDIT:

For example for this code: it shows correctly in google chrome but bootlint.com says it is not valid.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-multiple-selectp col-xs-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="values[]">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <span class="input-group-addon input-group-addon-remove">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Live example: http://bootsnipp-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/iframe/g07Xd

Comment: Please share your codes. It is not enough to put links.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has input addon to add icon or button and you can follow docs [button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <select class="form-control" >
    <option>Some option</option>
    <option>Some option</option>
  </select>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

and here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArefBenLazrek/117a93ye)

Comment: Thanks. I used your method. but please test here: bootlint.com. it return e006 error. We do not allowed insert select inside `input-group`

Comment: yes it was before your edit , the error cause is here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups                      Textual <input> s only
Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

Avoid using <textarea> elements here as their rows attribute will not be respected in some cases.